# How to insert data into an already created database in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          final games = await openDialog();
                          if (games == null || games.isEmpty) return;

                          setState(() => this.games = games);
                        },

                     
                     ---------
                     ---------

Future<String?> openDialog() => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Games',
              style: loginText,
            ),
          ),
          content: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Map<String, String> save = {'description': controller.text};
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles').add(save);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Save'))
          ],
        ),
      );
```

When the Save button is clicked, I want to be able to assign the texts entered to the 'description' value in the document created by the user while registering.

[image]

**Data saved in the database when a new user registers.**

[image]

When I click the save button, it saves to the database with a new document id, not to the database of the relevant user.

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles')
          .doc(...id generated by Firebase, Middle Columne ).set({'description': text,});

Answer (score 1):

The `add()` function specifically creates a new document in a collection, and generates a new ID.

It looks like you want to merge data to an existing record. In that case use

```
db.collection('yourcollection').doc('docId').set(save, SetOptions(merge : true));
```

---

It might be that the ID is incorrect. You can try to update an existing record, it will fail if it does not exist:

```
Future<void> update() {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles')
    .doc('Your-DOC-ID')
    .update(save)
    .then((value) => print("Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update: $error"));
}
```

Comment: It still creates a new id and puts the description value in it. I guess it's because I couldn't assign a specific 'doc-id'. But it is impossible for me to know the 'doc-id' assigned when the user was registered. So it should find that id itself and insert the description value into it.

Comment: @KKot it should not create a new record but merge the data. Try to use `update` method. It will fail if a record does not exist. Added example to the answer.

Comment: @KKot to update a record, it is mandatory to know it's `doc-id`. So, you need to find out a way to get that information. Firestore returns IDs on any data modification: create, update, delete. The same for collections.

Comment: After clicking the save button, I don't see any value in the console.

Comment: Try to add `async` to your Save function and `await` to the FirebaseFirestore.update.

Comment: It wasn't running the code without adding them. But isn't the problem that the update() function is not called somewhere? Where should I call this function?

Comment: Just replace your `FirebaseFirestore...add()` logic with `update`, e.g.:
`Map<String, String> save = {'description': controller.text};  
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles').document('Your-DOC-ID').update(save);`. And replace 'You-DOC-ID' with a real document id that you need to update.

Comment: It filled the description: ' ' in the doc-id saved in the database with the data I typed and clicked the save button. Then when I typed something else and clicked the save button, it worked again without any problems and updated the value opposite decription.

Comment: And if you need `upsert` logic, i.e. insert a record if does not exist, or update a record when it does exist, then use the initially mentioned `....document('Your-DOC-ID').set(save, SetOptions(merge : true));`.

Comment: There is no problem in the code. Communication with database, adding data, changing etc. Now, where I don't know the specific id, I need to fill that description value according to the id of the user when registering.

Comment: That is up to you what to use for UID, may be it will be a user email.